# Insert picture in Markdown/Notebook specifying size

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr, rnotebook

I want to make picture smaller and tried different ways but none of them worked.Please help

```
{r, include=F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.align="center", out.width=550, 
dpi=200)
include_graphics(path = "time.jpg")
```

I tried many things including fig.height or fig.width but none of them make picture smaller

Comment: Have you tried setting figure options in chunk line (ie, `{r, fig.width = 2}`) and not inside with `knitr::opts_chunk`?

Comment: Yes and I tried again, but nothing changes

Comment: Can you try `{r, out.width = "100px"}` and only `include_graphics` within chunk

Comment: no difference (